# Fetch a value from a codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a variable called `path` (its value is *"/`relative/somefolder/myimg.png`"*) in the code behind (xaml.cs) and I want to use this variable to set the value of the image source in XAML (UI). Can anyone tell how to do this?

Comment: What did you try to do so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In codebehind you can do it like this :

```
Uri path=new Uri(yourPath,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
yourImage.Source = new BitmapImage(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either set the value directly from code-behind (like Joh. already mentioned) or you could have a look at data binding to set it directly from XAML.
[Data Binding WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms750612(v=vs.100).aspx)